# Получить данные со страницы в виде json

Tags: javascript, json

Есть страница в которой просто написано 
в виде json, мне нужно как-то получать каждое из этих чтобы я мог с этим работать. как это реализовать?

[image: тот сайт на котором это и написано]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция в js: JSON.Parse(), которая принимает строку. Она будет возвращать вам объект, полученный в результате парсинга json. Чтобы получить данные  json, котрые находится на определенной странице, можно, например, использовать функцию fetch